Aligning raster with shapefile
I have a raster file which I need to align with a shapefile. I tried gdal warp to reproject it to EPSG 4326. When I tried doing it, I get an error message
ERROR 1: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for NETCDF:"/Users/pulaharoy/Downloads/Attributable_Days_2018-2023.nc":Attributable_days_above_18. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.
I think the problem is with the extent of the raster which is 0,-721: 1440,0 as opposed to the more conventional -180,-90:180,90. Any way I can fix the raster extent? 
